# правильное использование cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, linux, cin

Хочу научится правильно использовать `cin.ignore()`, но что-то не могу найти нужной информации по этому методу.

Как я понимаю этот метод может вообще не принимать аргументов, принимать количество пропускаемых символов, либо количество пропускаемых символов и символ разделитель. Что делает метод в первом случае, когда он не принимает аргументов? Как заменить этим методом следующий код:

```
while (std::cin.get() != '\n')
    continue;
```

Т.е., я понимаю, что в `cin.ignore()` нужно передать два аргумента, при этом вторым должен быть `'\n'`, но что передавать первым?
Ведь я не могу изначально знать какой длинны будет строка и сколько символов нужно будет пропустить: 10, 100, или 1000 или еще больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пишите так](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(т.е. задаете максимальное значение для типа `streamsize`)